# SQL Server - 'Transpose' binary columns into a single row if binary value=1. Use column names (comma separated) instead of binary values

Tags: sql-server

I have the following `dbo.Sales` table in SQL Server:

| item | United Kingdom | Germany | France | Spain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| X2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| X3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to prepare the dataset so that the binary columns are converted into a single row with comma separated values where the binary value = 1. However, I want the column names to be used rather than the binary values.

| item | Countries |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | United Kingdom, Germany, France |
| X2 | France, Spain |
| X3 | United Kingdom |

I have tried using `pivot` and `unpivot` without any success. Could anyone advise the best approach please.

Comment: Thiws is a denormalised design, your columns should be rows. Do you always have the same 4 columns? Please state your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT, your query would be (SQL server 2017 or above):

```
SELECT item
    ,STRING_AGG(countries, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY countries)
FROM (
    SELECT item
        ,countries
        ,value
    FROM (
        SELECT item
            ,[United Kingdom]
            ,Germany
            ,France
            ,Spain
        FROM dbo.Sales
        ) p
    UNPIVOT(value FOR countries IN (
                [United Kingdom]
                ,Germany
                ,France
                ,Spain
                )) AS unpvt
    WHERE VALUE = 1
    ) a
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: Do you know how to put countries in the Countries column in alphabetical order? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer with `order by Countries`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your columns are fixed, you can use a condition *case expression* in a *values* clause in conjunction with *string_agg* - requires SQL Server 2017+

```
select item, String_Agg(Countries, ', ') Countries
from t
cross apply(values
    (case when [united kingdom] = 1 then 'United Kingdom' end),
    (case when Germany = 1 then 'Germany' end),
    (case when France = 1 then 'France' end),
    (case when Spain = 1 then 'Spain' end)
)c(Countries)
group by Item
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are fixed:

```
SELECT item, STRING_AGG(countries, ',')
FROM (
    SELECT item, countries, value
    FROM sales p
    UNPIVOT(value FOR countries IN ([United Kingdom],Germany,France,Spain)) AS unpvt
    WHERE VALUE = 1
    ) a
GROUP BY item
```

if not:

```
declare @columns varchar(max)
select @columns = STUFF((select ',['+name+']' 
                         from sys.columns 
                         where  object_id = Object_id('sales') and 
                                name <>'item' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

exec('
SELECT item, STRING_AGG(countries, '','')
FROM (
    SELECT item, countries, value
    FROM sales p
    UNPIVOT(value FOR countries IN ('+@columns+')) AS unpvt
    WHERE VALUE = 1
    ) a
GROUP BY item')
```